# How to get the current Elastic APM instance in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, apm, elastic-apm

I have integrated `Elastic APM` to my Vue.js App accordingly to the documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/rum-js/current/vue-integration.html)

In addition to the default events `page-load` and `route-change` I want to add custom transactions/spans for some button clicks.

I am stucked with checking if there is already an existing transaction start which I could use to add a custom span:

```
const transaction = this.$apm.currentTransaction()
transaction.startSpan('custom_span', 'type_name');
transaction.end();
```

However getting the current transaction fails (first line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Elastic RUM agent has support for [click user interactions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/rum-js/current/supported-technologies.html#user-interactions), therefore you shouldn't need to manually start these type of transactions.

Regarding the failure in your code the correct API call is `getCurrentTransaction` and not `currentTransaction`.

Hope this helps.