# How to monitor user clicks with APM React

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, apm, elastic-apm, rum

I'm using *ElasticSearch APM RUM* in a *React* application.

Now, I already integrated the *APM* to the router, so that I can see the `route-change` transactions in *Kibana*.

Now I want to **track user clicks on a specific button**, to see, for example, how many users click on it. (In the [APM React docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/rum-js/current/react-integration.html), I can see only how to track **on component**, but here I need to track **on click**.)

**My questions are:**

1. Do I need to create a **Transaction** or **Span** for that?
2. How can I create this **Transaction**/**Span** manually, without wrapping a component for that?

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59352981/how-to-get-the-current-elastic-apm-instance-in-vue-js) helps but not answering my question, because according to the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/rum-js/current/supported-technologies.html#user-interactions):

> However, to avoid sending too many user-interaction transactions to the server, the agent discards transactions with no spans (e.g. no network activity)

And my case is a click that changing the UI.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you need to create a **Transaction** for that, because **Transaction** is a "flow" of the user. If you want to track it as **Span**, you need to be inside an **active Transaction**, and you don't have one*.

Now, according to [this doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/rum-js/current/custom-transactions.html), you need to create a custom transaction, then close it.

For example:

```js
const click = () => {
  const transaction = apm.startTransaction('UserClicked', 'custom')
  transaction.addLabels({ buttonText })

  originalClickAction()

  transaction.end()
}
```

Now you can use it with your JSX, `<Button text={buttonText} click={click} />`

Personally, I prefer to create wrapper for any code:

```js
export const monitor = (eventName, action, labels) => {
  const transaction = apm.startTransaction(eventName, 'custom')
  if (labels) transaction.addLabels(labels)

  return Promise.resolve(action(transaction))
    .finally(() => transaction.end())

}

// Usage

const click = () => monitor('UserClicked', originalClickAction, { buttonText })
```

---

* If you want to say that you are in the `page-load`/`route-change` transaction, you can't. Because the user might wait a while, looking on the page, before clicking on it. Actually, you can call it `route-change` because it is not.